# DateTimeFormatter adding a year to date after formatting

Tags: java, datetime-format

I am trying to convert a date of the format `2019-12-30` to a date with format `30-12-2019` and for this I thought of using `DateTimeFormatter` and I have the following code for this:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2019-12-30");
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-YYYY");
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

However, to my surprise, this returns an output:

```
30-12-2020
```

instead of the expected `30-12-2019`. If the date is set to `2019-11-30`, it correctly returns `30-11-2019`. I am doing something terribly wrong but I am not able to figure out what exactly. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [`DateTimeFormatter` documentation:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), indicating the symbol, meaning and examples:

> Y week-based-year year    1996; 96

So you're formatting the week-based-year, not the regular year. December 30th 2019 belongs to the first week of 2020, hence your output.

Use `yyyy` (year-of-era) or `uuuu` (year) instead of `YYYY` and you'll get 2019 instead.

Basically, `YYYY` should usually be used with `w` (week-of-week-based-year)  and `E` (day-of-week).

Answer (score 2):

Use `"dd-MM-yyyy"` instead of `"dd-MM-YYYY"`
Try the following code snippet to get expected result -

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2019-12-30");
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
System.out.println("date " + formatter.format(date)); // date 30-12-2019
```

Comment: You had an explanation as to why I should use `yyyy` before, that answer is much better. Can you please edit and add the explanation back?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-YYYY");` and notice that `Y` stands for *week-based-year*, which you probably don't want. Perhaps you want yout pattern to be `"dd-MM-uuuu"`. For more information on patterns, refer to the official Oracle documentation: [Patterns for Formatting and Parsing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns)